# Mumble (Snap) hotkeys stopepd working

Tags: 20.04, snap, mumble

Using Ubuntu 20.04.  My Mumble client installed via snap is no longer responding to my hotkey (shortcuts) set for voice activation.  Whisper/Shout, push to talk, etc...  none of the shortcut hotkeys are working as of the last 24-48 hours.  Worked like a charm before that.  Seem there was a snap update for this client that broke something.

Anyone else have experience with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that.
Can you run `snap connect mumble:audio-record` and test to see if that fixes it.